# Why 'Using index condition' even though condition within index?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Had a slow query which uses two columns so decided to add a composite index and alter the sorting. It is working great now. Execution time went down from almost a minute to under a second. But the `explain` output still displays '*Using index condition*'. Why?

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA 
WHERE source = 'book' AND uuid = 999 
ORDER BY uuid ASC;
```

Table columns:
[image: Table columns]

Index:

[image: Table index]

Explain output:
[image: Explain output]

Explain analyze output:

> -> Index lookup on TableA using source_uuid_index (source='book'), with index condition: (table.uuid = 999)  (cost=33679.16 rows=170038) (actual time=57.279..57.384 rows=4 loops=1)

The EXPLAIN data says that it is using the composite index, which makes sense. However, the EXPLAIN ANALYZE also says "`with index condition: (table.uuid = 999)`".

Why does it use `uuid` as an '*index condition*', being uuid in the index alongside `source`?

Comment: Do you mean why does it use the non-composite index? I think if so it may be because you're ordering by single field.

Comment: It uses the composite index actually

Comment: Well, isn't source_uuid_index is supposed to be used in the where filtering? You're filtering by both, so isn't it only natural for it to use the composite index there?

Comment: Exactly. That's good indeed. The value of the 'Extra' column on the 'Explain output' was the one annoying me. Turned out that the problem was the query itself. uuid is a varchar not an int. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why have `order by uuid` when you are limiting to a single uuid??

Comment: What version of MySQL?  I don't get ICP.  (Not even when comparing a number to a varchar).

Comment: @RickJames ```uuid``` can be misleading as it is not unique. Is a regular _varchar_ field, so there can be several records for the same ```source``` & ```uuid```. Additionally, sorting by ```uuid``` because you need to ```order by``` something and is better to use an index field rather than the table ```id```.

Comment: @RickJames about the versions, I tried with both ```mysql:5.7``` and ```mysql:8.0.20```. With MySQL workbench 8.0.0 and 8.0.20. Hope that helps!

Comment: @DavidS - Your self-Answer was the real solution.  Glad you found it; I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what's the cause.
The `uuid` column is type `varchar`. So I was querying wrongly. This is the right query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA 
WHERE source = 'book' AND uuid = '999'
ORDER BY uuid ASC;
```

Explain output:
[image]